# Transform a case class to another by unwrapping types in Scala 3

Tags: scala, generics, scala-3, generic-derivation, match-types

I have a enum that represents a container and two case classes:

```scala
enum Container[+A]:
  case Value(value: A)
  case Default(default: A)

  def get: A = this match
    case Value(value)     => value
    case Default(default) => default

case class PersonTemplate(name: Container[String], age: Container[Int], enabled: Container[Boolean])
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, enabled: Boolean)
```

and I want to write a generic function in Scala 3 that converts all case classes like `PersonTemplate` into their counterpart like `Person`, something like:

```scala
def extract[I <: Product, O <: Product](input: I): O = ???

val initial = PersonTemplate(Value("John"), Default(12), Default(true))
val final = extract[PersonTemplate, Person](initial)
// Result: Person("John", 12, true)
```

I tried several approaches but none of them was succesfull and mainly because I don't understand how to use Scala 3 `Tuple` that to me looks different from Scala 2 Shapeless' `HList` (and even in shapeless I'm not that good).

My overall approach was:

1. Convert the case class in a Tuple. For this I found `Tuple.fromProductTyped`
2. Constrain each element to be a `Container[_]`. I found `Tuple.IsMappedBy` to guarantee the tuple has the correct shape and `Tuple.InverseMap` that seems to extract the type inside the container. I'm not sure where to put this code, though.
3. Apply a (poly?)function to each value that calls `Container.get`. With the little I found around the net I ended up using a lot of `.asInstanceOf` and it didn't seem right to me.
4. Convert the resulting `Tuple` to the output type using `summon[Mirror.Of[O]].fromProduct(output)`

For sake of completeness, this is the last code I tried, that of course doesn't work:

```scala
def resolve[I <: Product: Mirror.ProductOf, O: Mirror.ProductOf](input: I): O =
  val processed =
    Tuple
      .fromProductTyped(input)
      .map { [T] => (value: T) => ??? }

  summon[Mirror.Of[O]].fromProduct(processed)

type ExtractG = [G] =>> G match {
  case Container[a] => a
}

def process[I <: Tuple, O <: Tuple](input: I)(using Tuple.IsMappedBy[Container][I]): O =
  input.map { [A] => (a: A) =>
    a.asInstanceOf[Container[_]].get.asInstanceOf[ExtractG[A]]
  }.asInstanceOf[O]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you don't mind a bit of casting, you can do this:

```scala
def unwrapper[From <: Product, To](
  using To: Mirror.ProductOf[To],
  From: Mirror.ProductOf[From],
  ev: From.MirroredElemTypes =:= Tuple.Map[To.MirroredElemTypes, Container]
): (From => To) =
  from => To.fromProduct {
    from.productIterator
        .toArray
        .map(_.asInstanceOf[Container[_]].get)
        .foldRight[Tuple](EmptyTuple)(_ *: _)
  }

@main def run =
  import Container._
  val unTemplate = unwrapper[PersonTemplate, Person]
  println(unTemplate(PersonTemplate(Value("foo"), Default(42), Default(false))))
```

Requested `From` and `ev` only serve to prove the type-safety of all the casting. IMO the mirror machinery lacks in ability to operate on things in a type-safe way without macros like shapeless can.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean here. Do you know if shapeless is being updated for Scala 3?

Comment: There is some work being done in v3.0.0-M1 branch, but the biggest part of currently working code relates to typeclass derivation. I'm unsure if shapeless will still have the same type-safe metaprogramming arsenal as it does in Scala 2